# How to delete the root node in a 1-layer BST

Tags: c++, c

I have a simple BST node struct:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
}
```

Back in ***C***, the constructor would be like:

```
Node* construct_node(int value){
    Node* node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node)); 
    node->data = value; 
    node->right = NULL; 
    node->left = NULL; 
}
```

Making it is easy to delete the root, since it is just another dynamically allocated node.

In ***C++***, however, the constructor doesn't return anything, and the root is the only node that is statically allocated.

```
Node::Node(const int& value, Node* left, Node* right) {
    this->value = value;
    this->left = left;
    this->right = right;
}
```

Is there any way to go around this so that deleting the root is possible just like in C, even if the user declares it statically in the main? Or a way to strict the user to declare it only using 'new'? Keeping it 1-layer without adding another class as the tree holding nodes by pointing to the root one.

Comment: Why not dynamically allocate the node in C++?

Comment: The constructor would be "like" that, but this code is wrong because there are no `return` statements.

Comment: @MikeCAT - How would you dynamically allocate it except if you declare it as dynamic in the main? I need to be able to delete it even if the user declares it statically.

Comment: Exit your program, and the OS will delete that for you.

Comment: You should create a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This would help to think about your intended usage, and might already give you the answer. If not it's easier to help then.

Comment: What is a 1 layer BST and how does it differ from a Binary Tree or a BST?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply not define a constructor of this type at all. Just create a default constructor,

```
Node::Node(){}
```

And make all members private with getters. This will make this constructor useless.
Now create a function which behaves just like the one in C,

```
Node* Node::new_node(int val, Node *l, Node *r){
      Node *n = new Node();
      n->left = l;
      n->right = r;
      return n;
}
```

This will force people to use this constructor only.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think you have some confusion about pointers between C and C++. They're the same thing. There's nothing at all that keeps you from writing this method in C++:

```
Node * construct_node(int value) {
    Node * node = new Node(value, nullptr, nullptr);
    return node;
}
```

At which point, all that really changes in deleting the node is that you use:

```
delete node;
```

Instead of:

```
free(node);
```

Everything else remains the same. Now, you have to decide what happens when you delete a Node. Do you want destructor that deletes the left and right nodes recursively? Or do you let them potentially get lost? So you're not done.